# Renaming a file to a shorter name easily using something like brace expansion

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

So I know about using braces when backing up a file to making this sweet and easy like so:

`cp -v original.xml{,.backup}`

But if I wanted to restore the original I would have to do this

`cp -v original.xml.backup original.xml`

Is there a neat way to shorten this in a way similar to how brace expansion shortened the first command?

Comment: it can get even shorter  `cp -v original.xml{*,}` but then this will work for one file only. Just an idea!

Comment: @val0x00ff That's a nifty way to truncate as well I'll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the comma on the other side

```
cp -v original.xml{.backup,}
```

Comment: Awesome seems obvious now!

Comment: @jmathew Good moment to learn what the brace expansion actually does!

Comment: @Bernhard Ha yea I should. Like a lot of unix concepts brace expansion is one of those things which I've only ever learned *just* enough of to get by.

Comment: @jmathew Keeping up with new questions on this site and reading old, top voted question, should get you going quite a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, with `tcsh`, `bash` or `zsh`:

```
cp -v original.xml.backup !#:$:r
```

- `!`: history expansion
- `#`: current command line
- `:$`: last word
- `:r`: get the *rest* (that is, without the extension)

(yes, I know, too long, twisting fingers too much)

Comment: Wow thats complicated but definitely cool. I didn't know I could learn so much from 6 characters!